# Definitely delete more than 1000 images from an image collection in Google Earth Engine using the code editor!

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, delete

I need to definitely delete more than 1000 images from an image collection in Google Earth Engine using the code editor.

After some attempts I arrived to the following code:

```
var deleteA = function(image) {
  
    return ee.data.deleteAsset(image,true);

};

print(collection.map(deleteA));
```

But it didn´t work. I dont´t understand the reason. Do you what's wrong in my code?

Comment: From the doc [`ee.data.deleteAsset(assetId, callback)`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-deleteasset) where: "assetId String 
The ID of the asset to delete". See also [`ee.Image.id`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-id) "Returns the ID of a given element within a collection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. Although one still need to click 'OK' for the message 'Execute ee.data.deleteAsset()? This will modify Asset or Task state.'

```
function deleteChildren(ImgCollection){
var n = ImgCollection.size().getInfo();
  var colList = ImgCollection.toList(n);
  var assetFolder = 'projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/*your_username*/*Image Collection name*/';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var img = ee.Image(colList.get(i));
    var id = img.id().getInfo() || 'image_'+i.toString();
    var assetId = assetFolder+id;
    ee.data.deleteAsset(assetId);
  }
}
deleteChildren(My_Asset_Collection_to_Delete)
```

Comment: Does this still work? There appears to be an error with finding the images, possibly due to cloud assets?